# Как преобразовать полученный json файл к нужному виду?

Tags: php, объекты

При получении post-запроса, php скрипт декодирует полученные данные в json формат и записывает в файл token_data.json, находящийся на сервере

php скрипт, который получает, преобразовывает и записывает пост-запрос:

**postJson.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
$json = json_encode($_POST);
$file = fopen('token_data.json','w+');
fwrite($file,$json);
fclose($file);
?>
```

а собственно полученный объект json выглядит так:

**token_data.json**

```
{"pseudoID":"353597872677244",
"latitude":"45.24367",
"longitude":"38.97344",
"velocity":"1",
"distance":"0",
"date":"14.05.2021_18:39:24",
"azimuth":"260.5",
"accuracy":"4.9"}
```

И вот, во что мне необходимо преобразовать данный объект:
**token_data.json**

```
[pseudoID] =>{"latitude":"45.24367", //где pseudoID - значение из объекта, что 
//находится выше - "353597872677244"
"longitude":"38.97344",
"velocity":"1",
"distance":"0",
"date":"14.05.2021_18:39:24",
"azimuth":"260.5",
"accuracy":"4.9"}
```

Какими методами это можно реализовать?
P.S. данные махинации нужны для того, чтобы данные были более упорядоченными.

Comment: кто такой `ID` ? и зачем это нужно складывать в массив? И почему после стрелки `{}` а не `[]` ? вам нужен объект? ничего не понятно

Comment: а сколько таких элементов в json? один или несколько?

Comment: на счёт ID поправил - там pseudoID, значение из объекта. Эти значения нужно складывать для того, что таких объектов будет около 60 штук, и для упорядочивания, нужно присвоить каждому уникальный pseudoID. Стрелки там потому, что на сервер приходит объект, а не массив

Comment: Если приходит объект, а не массив, то не сможет прийти 60 штук

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [];
$jsonDecoded = json_decode(file_get_contents('token_data.json'), true);
$id = $jsonDecoded['pseudoID'];
unset($jsonDecoded['pseudoID']);
$arr[$id] = $jsonDecoded;
```

Comment: если наличие самого ключа внутри не критично, то проще `array_column([$decoded], null, 'pseudoID')`

Comment: @teran да в таком случае можно и `$arr[$jsonDecoded['pseudoID']] = $jsonDecoded;`))

Comment: ) действительно.